# Template function to print a Thrust vector

Tags: c, templates, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I'm writing a `matrix` template class that prints to both file and `std::cout`, i.e.:

```
matrix<float> myMat;
...
myMat.cout(...)         // print to std::cout
myMat.write("out.txt")  // print to file
```

Both will share a common underlying printing function which I'm trying to implement as a template too, since I've seen different examples that use `thrust::copy` to write data to both `std::cout` and files.

Below is the skeleton of what I've done, but it **is currently outputting garbage. Could anyone point to some errors** I may have made? For example, am I allowed to pass `std::cout` around like this?

```
template <typename data_T> matrix {
    ...

    template <typename out_T> int printTo(out_T &out, ...) {
        data_T *start = ..., *end = ...;
        ...
        thrust::copy(start, end, std::ostream_iterator<data_T>(out, " "));
        ...
    }

    int cout(...) {
        ...
        printTo(std::cout, ...);
        ...
    }

    int write(char* path, ...) {
        ...
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open(path);
        printTo(file, ...);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

- Changing to `int printTo(std::ostream &out, ...) {...}` does not fix the problem.
- *More info*: I read data into the matrix from a `thrust::device_vector<T>`, say `dvec`, and convert it to a `data_T` pointer `pvec` using `thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&dvec[0])` (as the CUBLAS library uses raw pointers). I then operate on `pvec` and then want to print it out.
- I've tried printing from a pointer of the original `thrust::device_vector` directly (i.e. `*dvec`) and it **does** work: `thrust::copy((*dvec).begin(), (*dvec).begin() + n ...)`. So why can I copy only using `*dvec` iterators and not the raw pointer cast `pvec`?

Comment: You don't need to make `printTo` a template function. Simply have the first argument be an `std::ostream` reference.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks - I've changed it to `int printTo(std::ostream &out, ...) {...}` as suggested, but it's still outputting garbage. Any other ideas?

Comment: How do you store the "data"? How do you actually initialize `start` and `end`?

Comment: I read data into the `matrix` from a `thrust::device_vector<T>`, say `dvec`, and convert it to a `data_T` pointer `pvec` using `thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&dvec[0])` (as the CUBLAS library uses raw pointers). I then operate on `pvec` and then want to print it out.

Comment: I've tried printing from a pointer of the original `thrust::device_vector` directly (i.e. `*dvec`) and it **does** work: `thrust::copy((*dvec).begin(), (*dvec).begin() + n ...)`. So why can I copy only from `*dvec` and not the raw pointer cast `pvec`?

Comment: What assumptions are you making about the packing of the data?  For instance, on the raw pointer `pvec`, does printing the first element work correctly, but every element after the first is garbage?  In other words, iterating using a raw pointer may not take into account some underlying data-structure implementation techniques that iterating using an actual iterator compensates for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `raw_pointer_cast` here. That will fool Thrust into thinking that you've got a pointer to data on the host, which is why your code isn't giving you what you expect. I would have expected your code to just crash.

To copy a `device_vector` to an `ostream_iterator`, just use `thrust::copy` directly:

```
thrust::device_vector<float> vec = ...

thrust::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Much appreciated @JaredHoberock - how can I store the iterator vec.begin()? I actually loop over the thrust vector reading chunks of data since a submatrix of a larger matrix may not be stored contiguously in memory.

Comment: You can use `thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator i = vec.begin();` or `thrust::device_ptr<float> ptr = vec.data();`.

Comment: Thanks @JaredHoberock, but what if I want to use the iterator with my own template type: `thrust::device_vector<data_T>::iterator i = ...`? I get a compile error `expected a ";"` if I change from `<float>` to `<data_T>`.